# Laravel: Validation unique on update

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I know this question has been asked many times before but no one explains how to get the id when you're validating in the model.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,10'
```

My validation rule is in the model so how do I pass the ID of the record to the validation rule.

Here is my models/User

```
protected $rules_update = [
    'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'.$id,
    'first_name' => "required",
    'last_name' => "required",
    'password' => "required|min:6|same:password_confirm",
    'password_confirm' => "required:min:6|same:password",
    'password_current' => "required:min:6"
];
```

models/BaseModel

```
    protected $rules = array();

public $errors;

/*
    * @data: array, Data to be validated
    * @rules: string, rule name in model 
*/

public function validate($data, $rules = "rules") {

    $validation  = Validator::make($data, $this->$rules);

    if($validation->passes()) {
        return true;
    }

    $this->errors = $validation->messages();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would also love to know how the $id is passed to the model. I'm using the way/database package and have the same issue.

Comment: I've added my answer below.

Comment: Me too, having the same issue

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One simple solution.

In your Model

```
protected $rules = [
    'email_address' => 'sometimes|required|email|unique:users',
    ..
];
```

In your Controller, action:update

```
...
$rules = User::$rules;
$rules['email_address'] = $rules['email_address'] . ',id,' . $id;
$validationCertificate  = Validator::make($input, $rules);
```

Comment: Cannot access protected property App\User::$rules

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumarBarik What version is your Laravel?

Comment: my laravel version is 7.x

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumarBarik My answer was in 2014, for version 4.x. So, I think for version 7 you have a different solution. Check the other answers below, or create a new question on Stack overflow, and add the link here to us to help you.

Answer (score 129):

Just a side note, most answers to this question talk about `email_address` while in Laravel's inbuilt auth system, the email field name is just `email`. Here is an example how you can validate a unique field, i.e. an email on the update:

In a [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation), you do like this:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user->id,
  ];
}
```

Or if you are validating your data in a controller directly:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
  $request->validate([
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
  ]);
}
```

**Update**:
If you are updating the signed in user and aren't injecting the `User` model into your route, you may encounter undefined property when accessing `id` on `$this->user`. In that case, use:

```php
public function rules()
    {
      return [
          'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user()->id,
      ];
    }
```

A more elegant way since Laravel 5.7 is:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => ['required', 'email', \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user()->id)]
    ];
}
```

P.S: I have added some other rules, i.e. required and email, in order to make this example clear for newbies.

Comment: I am using `FormRequest`, and this is exactly what I needed to do.

Comment: How should I access/provide $this->user() or other models in FormRequest? like $this->article() in ArticleFormRequest

Comment: @KrzysztofDziuba do you want to access signed in user?

Comment: Using `\Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique()` it's really the most elegant way. For me, that was the best suggestion. Thanks

Comment: This great for unique validation. Now I want to validate the image for update but only if user uploads new on.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you so much.

Comment: What about other users data? like the super admin updating one of the users data, how can I pass to `User $user`? I only passing the id of the user in route (/users/update/1)

Comment: How to validate other than id col

Answer (score 39):

There is an elegant way to do this. If you are using Resource Controllers, your link to edit your record will look like this:

> /users/{user}/edit **OR** /users/1/edit

And in your UserRequest, the rule should be like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'unique:users,name,' . $this->user
        ],
    ];
}
```

Or if your link to edit your record look like this:

> /users/edit/1

You can try this also:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'unique:users,name,' . $this->id
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: This answer is the best and most elegant. I have a question. Link to my edit record looks like `/users/{user}/edit` and I want to prevent my `unique:users,name` being able to be updated while other fields can be updated. How would I achieve it?

Answer (score 21):

From Laravel 5.7, this works great

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

[Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:](https://devdocs.io/laravel~5.7/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 12):

Test below code:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'. $id .'ID'
```

Where `ID` is the primary id of the table

Comment: `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'. $id .',user_id'` worked for me. Here `user_id` is primary key of the table. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If i understand what you want:

> 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'. $id .''

In model update method, for exemple, should receive the $id with parameter.

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: Does the $id parameter get passed into model. I've already tried'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,{{$id}}' with no luck'

Comment: {{$id}} works only in views with blade. So you shoud use string scape: 'unique:users,email_address,'. $id .'' or "unique:users,email_address,". $id .""

Comment: Doesn't work. Error below 
1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­models/­User.php42
0. Illuminate\Exception\Handler handleShutdown
<#unknown>0
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']'

Comment: You can show your model method or print a image from error page?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution:

For Update:

```
public function controllerName(Request $request, $id)

{

    $this->validate($request, [
        "form_field_name" => 'required|unique:db_table_name,db_table_column_name,'.$id
    ]);

    // the rest code
}
```

That's it. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 8):

In `Laravel 8.x` you can use `Rule::unique` method as well

***Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:***

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'max:60', Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($post->id)],
    ]);

    $post->update($validatedData);
    
    return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('status', 'post updated successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public function rules()
{

    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        {
            return [];
        }
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|unique:permissions|max:255',
                'display_name' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [                    
                'name' => 'unique:permissions,name,'.$this->get('id').'|max:255',
                'display_name' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        default:break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, the id could be part of the URL and so you will find it in the route parameters:
$this->route({field_name})
eg:
$this->route('id')

Comment: Its' always better to mention reference you copied the code from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update

Comment: you have to pass hidden field with id to use $this->get('id')

Answer (score 7):

an even simpler solution tested with version 5.2

in your model

```
// validator rules
public static $rules = array(
    ...
    'email_address' => 'email|required|unique:users,id'
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try this.

```
protected $rules_update = [
    'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'. $this->id,
    'first_name' => "required",
    'last_name' => "required",
    'password' => "required|min:6|same:password_confirm",
    'password_confirm' => "required:min:6|same:password",
    'password_current' => "required:min:6"
];
```

Answer (score 7):

**The Best Option is here try just once no need more code when unique validation on updating data**

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,' . $userId,
```

**here**`email`**is field name and** `users` **is table name and** `email_address` **is table attribute name which you want unique and** `$userid` **is updating row id**

Answer (score 7):

**Do One step in controller**

**Works Fine with Laravel 9**

```
$request->validate([
        'name'=>'required|unique:categories,name,'.$id,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$rules = [
    "email" => "email|unique:users, email, '.$id.', user_id"
];
```

In Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique;

Unique validation will parse string validation to Rule object

Unique validation has pattern: **unique:%s,%s,%s,%s,%s'**

Corresponding with: table name, column, ignore, id column, format wheres

```
/**
 * Convert the rule to a validation string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return rtrim(sprintf('unique:%s,%s,%s,%s,%s',
        $this->table,
        $this->column,
        $this->ignore ?: 'NULL',
        $this->idColumn,
        $this->formatWheres()
    ), ',');
}
```

Comment: I like where you got there. But I'm just not sure on how to apply this to a model's rules. Where should I replace {{$id}}?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a separate rules method. You can use easier the following syntax.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => "required|unique:users,email,{$this->id}"
    ]; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i would solve that by doing something like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         'name' => 
            'required|min:2|max:255|unique:courses,name,'.\Request::get('id'),
    ];
}
```

Where you get the id from the request and pass it on the rule

Comment: The Laravel docs warn of this technique as it can introduce a security vulnerability. Imagine an attacker can modify the rules by supplying anything to the `id` parameter.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple and elegant way to do this. If you are passing the user_id in a body request or through a query parameter.
e.g

```
/update/profile?user_id=
```

Then in your request rules

```php
  public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            'last_name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => ['required','email', 'string', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($request->user_id )],
            'phone_number' => ['required', 'string', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($request->user_id )],
        ];
    }
```

Better Still, you can pass in `auth->id()` in place of `$request->user_id` to get the login user id.

Answer (score 3):

Found the easiest way, working fine while I am using Laravel 5.2

```
public function rules()

{

switch ($this->method()) {
    case 'PUT':
        $rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
            'gender'                => 'required',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,id,:id',
            'password'              => 'required|min:5',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:5|same:password',
        ];
        break;

    default:
        $rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
            'gender'                => 'required',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|min:5',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:5|same:password',
        ];
        break;
}

return $rules;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I couldn't pull the id using ":id", so I did something like this: `if (in_array($this->method(), ['PUT', 'PATCH'])) { $rules['order'] .= ",{$this->route('videos')->id}"; }`

Comment: "id,:id" Not worked for me dear in edit/update mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use model classpath, if you don't want to hard code the table name.

```
function rules(){
    return [
        'email' => ['required','string',
         Rule::unique(User::class,'email')->ignore($this->id)]
    ];
}
```

Here $this->id is either 0 or the record Id to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

Most answers to this question refer to email_address, but in Laravel's inbuilt authentication system, the email field name is just email. Here is an example of validating a unique field, i.e. an email on the update:

Form Requests look like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
      return [
          'email' => [ 'required','email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id ?? 0)]];
    }
```

**?? 0 If you use this then if hare id does not exist this request will not give you an error**

Save
Whenever you access the id property of $this->user, you may encounter an undefined property if you haven't injected the User model into your route. If that is the case, use:

```
public function rules()
    {
      return [
          'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->user()->id ?? 0,
      ];
    }
```

**?? 0 If you use this then if hare id does not exist this request will not give you an error**

Answer (score 2):

Use for Laravel 6.0

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Form validation
        $request->validate([
            'category_name'   =>  [
                'required',
                'max:255',
                 Rule::unique('categories')->ignore($id),
            ]
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After researching a lot on this laravel validation topic including unique column, finally got the best approach. Please have a look

In your controller

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
         public function saveUser(Request $request){
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),User::rules($request->get('id')),User::$messages);
                if($validator->fails()){
                    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
                }
            }
    }
```

`saveUser` method can be called for add/update user record.

In you model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public static function rules($id = null)
    {
        return [
            'email_address' => 'required|email|unique:users,email_address,'.$id,
            'first_name' => "required",
            'last_name' => "required",
            'password' => "required|min:6|same:password_confirm",
            'password_confirm' => "required:min:6|same:password",
            'password_current' => "required:min:6"
        ];
    }
    public static $messages = [
        'email_address.required' => 'Please enter email!',
        'email_address.email' => 'Invalid email!',
        'email_address.unique' => 'Email already exist!',
        ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing. I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this but this is what i came up with.

Model/User.php

```
protected $rules = [
    'email_address' => 'sometimes|required|email|unique:users,email_address, {{$id}}',
];
```

Model/BaseModel.php

```
public function validate($data, $id = null) {


      $rules = $this->$rules_string;

     //let's loop through and explode the validation rules
     foreach($rules as $keys => $value) {

        $validations = explode('|', $value);

        foreach($validations as $key=>$value) {

            // Seearch for {{$id}} and replace it with $id
            $validations[$key] = str_replace('{{$id}}', $id, $value);

        }
        //Let's create the pipe seperator 
        $implode = implode("|", $validations);
        $rules[$keys] = $implode;

     }
     ....

  }
```

I pass the $user_id to the validation in the controller

Controller/UserController.php

```
public function update($id) { 

   .....

    $user = User::find($user_id);

    if($user->validate($formRequest, $user_id)) {
      //validation succcess 
    } 

    ....


}
```

Comment: I ended up just using watson/validating

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it too.

Answer (score 1):

Test below code:

```php
$validator = Validator::make(
            array(
              'E-mail'=>$request['email'],
             ),
            array(
              'E-mail' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$request['id'],
             ));
```

Comment: Try not to use request parameters directly in your validation rules. An attacker can modify the parameters supplied to the controller (even let the `id` parameter be `0|nullable` or worse).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 1):

While updating any Existing Data Write validator as following:

```
'email' => ['required','email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)]
```

This will skip/ignore existing user's id's unique value matching for the specific column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will want to ignore the record you are updating when performing an update, you will want to use `ignore` as mentioned by some others. But I prefer to receive an instance of the `User` rather then just an ID. This method will also allow you to do the same for other models

Controller

```
    public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->update($request->all());

        return back();
    }
```

UserRequest

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required',
                \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('users')->ignoreModel($this->route('user')),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

update: use `ignoreModel` in stead of `ignore`

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to do it ,

Write it at your controller

```
$this->validate($request,[
     'email'=>['required',Rule::unique('yourTableName')->ignore($request->id)]
]);
Note : Rule::unique('yourTableName')->ignore($idParameter) , here $idParameter you can receive from get url also you can get it from hidden field.
Most important is don't forget to import Rule at the top.
```

Answer (score 1):

If a login user want to update the email then auth() helper function will give us the login user id auth()->user()->id

[Laravel helpers#method-auth](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-auth)

```
   Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore(auth()->user()->id),
],
```

]);

if Admin want to change the specific user information from User list then validation will be like this :

```
 Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($request->user),
],
```

[Laravel validation#rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)

$request object contain the current route related model objects. Which gives the model.

```
Try dd($request)
```

Answer (score 1):

The **PUT/PATCH** request doesn't support `multipart/form-data` and will not populate **$_FILES** so If you are using **POST** method on **UPDATE** then use the route name in switch method.

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->route()->getName()) {
    case 'users.update':
        $rules = [
        'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
        'gender'                => 'required',
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,id,:id',
        'password'              => 'required|min:5',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:5|same:password',
        ];
        break;

    default:
        $rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
            'gender'                => 'required',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|min:5',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:5|same:password',
        ];
        break;
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$rules = $user->isDirty('email') ? \User::$rules : array_except(\User::$rules, 'email');
```

Then in validation:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(\Input::all(), $rules, \User::$messages);
```

The logic is if the email address in the form is different, we need to validated it, if the email hasn't changed, we don't need to validate, so remove that rule from validation.

Answer (score 0):

For `unique` rule in the controller - which obviously will be different for the `store` method and the `update` method, I usually make a function within the controller for `rules` which will return an array of rules.

```php
protected function rules($request)
{
    $commonRules = [
        'first_name' => "required",
        'last_name' => "required",
        'password' => "required|min:6|same:password_confirm",
        'password_confirm' => "required:min:6|same:password",
        'password_current' => "required:min:6"
    ];

    $uniqueRules = $request->id

          //update
        ? ['email_address' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email' . $request->get('id')]]

          //store
        : ['email_address' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email']];


    return array_merge($commonRules, $uinqueRules);
}
```

Then in the respective `store` and `update` methods

```php
$validatedData = $request->validate($this->rules($request));
```

This saves from defining two different rule sets for store and update methods.

If you can afford to compromise a bit on readability, it can also be

```php
protected function rules($request)
{
    return [
        'first_name' => "required",
        'last_name' => "required",
        'password' => "required|min:6|same:password_confirm",
        'password_confirm' => "required:min:6|same:password",
        'password_current' => "required:min:6",
        'email_address' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email' . $request->id ?: null]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Do not use request parameters like this directly. An attacker can modify the `id` parameter to be anything.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 0):

I read the previous post, but none approach the real problem. We need use the rule unique to apply on add and edit case. I use this rule on edit and add case and work fine.

In my solution i use rule function from Request Class.

1. I sent id over hidden input form field on edit form.
2. On the Rule function, we find by unique column and get the record.
3. Now evaluate the situation. If exist record and id are equal the unique must be not activate (that's mean edit record).

On the code:

```
public function rules()
    {
        //
        $user = User::where('email', $this->email)->first();
        //
        $this->id = isset($this->id) ? $this->id : null;
        $emailRule = (($user != null) && ($user->id == $this->id)) ? 'required|email:rfc,dns|max:255' : 'required|unique:users|email:rfc,dns|max:255';
        //        
        return [
            //
            'email'            =>  $emailRule,                
            //
        ];
        //


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm someone can try this. Here I have used soft delete checker. You could omit the last: `id,deleted_at, NULL` if your model doesn't have soft delete implementation.

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'PUT':
            $emailRules = "required|unique:users,email,{$this->id},id,deleted_at,NULL";
            break;
        default:
            $emailRules = "required|unique:users,email,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL";
            break;
    }

    return [
        'email' => $emailRules,
        'display_name' => 'nullable',
        'description' => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in my case when i convert $id to integer type its work correctly so we have

```
'email_address'=>'unique:users,email_address,'.intval($id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
Rule::unique('leads')->whereNull('deleted_at')->ignore($this->id);
```

Use this, it will ignore the record that you want to update.

```
ignore($this->id)
```