# Laravel unique rules on update, not working properly

Tags: laravel-5, unique, updates, rules

From [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587833/laravel-validation-unique-on-update) answer I am trying to update department data. Code as below :

```
$id = Crypt::decrypt($id); 
        $rules = Department::$rules;

        $rules['name']              = $rules['name'] . ',id,' . $id;
        $rules['department_code']   = $rules['department_code'] . ',id,' . $id;

        dump($rules);

        $validator = Validator::make($data = $request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        $department = Department::findOrFail($id);
```

But the validator says :

> The department code has already been taken.
>
> The name has already been taken.

So whats wrong ?

My `rules` array is:

```
public static $rules = [
        'name'              =>  'required|unique:departments|max:255', 
        'department_code'   =>  'required|unique:departments|max:127',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `$rules` array as:

```
public static $rules = [
        'name'              =>  'required|max:255|unique:departments', 
        'department_code'   =>  'required|max:127|unique:departments',
    ];
```

Then you can use it to append `id` in the rules.

Comment: I have changed rules to `public static $rules = [
     'name'     =>  'required|max:255|unique:departments', 
     'department_code'   =>  'required|max:127|unique:departments',
    ];` . Now `name` rules works fine but still getting message `The department code has already been taken.`

Comment: What is the name of the column for `department_code` in your table? If it is other than `department_code` then you have to provide in the rule as `unique:departments,code`. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique)