# Laravel Getting sql error when trying to give unique field validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

This is from validation that I have used for tag form validation

```
public function rules()
{
     return [
         'name' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tags,name,'.$this->tag,
     ];
}
```

My controller code

```
public function update(TagValidation $request, Tag $tag )
{
    $tag->update($request->all());
}
```

I am trying to avoid unique filed validation problem when trying to update. After use

```
unique:tags,name,'.$this->tag
```

I am getting below sql error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name:"abc"' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tags` where `name` = abc and `name:"abc"` <> {"id":14 and `created_at:"2020-06-13T16:24:36`.`000000Z"` = updated_at:"2020-06-13T16:46:44.000000Z"})
```

But I have name column in database and store is working fine If I not use $this->tag in validation.

Comment: i would assume you want to pass the value of some field to the rule (perhaps the model's id), not the model instance itself when using `$this->tag`?

Comment: If I use $this->id , I am getting "The name has already been taken."

Comment: `$this->tag` is a model instance ... you are concatenating a model instance to the string you are building (which serializes the model), not passing a single value like the id there ... `$this->tag->id` would be the id of the tag

Comment: After use $this->tag->id , I am getting validation error "The name has already been taken." After see this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587833/laravel-validation-unique-on-update

I have used model instance.

Comment: and my route is tags/14/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the id of the record you want to ignore the unique rule for which I would assume is that tag:

```
 'name' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tags,name,'. $this->tag->id,
```

Or you can use the object version of the Rule which you can just pass the model directly to:

```
'name' => [
    'required', 'max:50', 'min:3', 
    Rule::unique('tags')->ignore($this->tag),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

take care because unique validation is

**unique:table,column,except**,idColumn

You are passing the value anme of tag but is not necessary

You actually use:

```
return [
   'name' => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:tags,name,'.$this->tag,
];
```

but you need use this I show you working example for use the same validation on store and update (POST and PUT method):

```
public function rules()
{
    if ($this->method() == 'PUT') 
    {
        return [
             'name' => 'required|unique:tags,name,'.$this->id.',id',
        ];
    }elseif ($this->method() == 'POST'){
         return [
             'name' => 'required|unique:tags,name'
         ];
    }
}
```

Inclusive on Laravel 7* you can use Model directly

```
public function rules()
{
    // Check Create or Update
    if ($this->method() == 'PUT') 
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:App\Tag,name,'.$this->id.',id'
        ];
    }elseif ($this->method() == 'POST'){
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:App\Tag,name'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this ans where they given smaller solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587833/laravel-validation-unique-on-update, but  I am just getting sql error.