# How to validate a unique field on a record update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am recently started a laravel project to control some activities, but I am currently having issues with the validation specifically when updating a specific record on a table that contains unique values

A couple of notes a started this project a couple of days of the launch of laravel 8 last month so perhaps there some changes that are afecting me.

These are my migrations

The first one is a user with its data,
...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //para hacer insersion

class CrearTablaUsuarios extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->increments('id_usuario');
            $table->unique('id_usuario');
            $table->string('nombre_usuario',255);
            $table->string('apellido_usuario',255);
            $table->string('foto_usuario', 255);
            $table->string('alias',255);
            $table->unique('alias');
            $table->string('contraseña',255);
            $table->text('respuesta_pregunta');
            $table->string('telefono_usuario',255);
            $table->unique('telefono_usuario');
            $table->text('correo');
            $table->unique('correo');
            $table->integer('id_tipo_usuario')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_tipo_usuario')->references('id_tipo_usuario')->on('tipos_usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('id_cargo_usuario')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_cargo_usuario')->references('id_cargo_usuario')->on('cargos_usuarios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('estado_usuario');
            $table->date('fecha_registro');
            $table->date('fecha_retiro')->nullable();
        });

       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::dropIfExists('usuarios');
    }
}
```

...

Second is a table to describe user types
...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //para hacer insersion

class CrearTablaTiposUsuarios extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tipos_usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_tipo_usuario');
            $table->unique('id_tipo_usuario');
            $table->string('nombre_tipo_usuario', 255);
            $table->unique('nombre_tipo_usuario');
            $table->text('descripcion_tipo_usuario');
        });

           // Insert some stuff
        DB::table('tipos_usuarios')
                ->insert(
                [ 
                    [
                        'nombre_tipo_usuario' => 'Administrador',
                        'descripcion_tipo_usuario' => 'Este tipo de usuario se encarga de manejar la aplicación y tiene control total, ademas de ser el unico que puede crear usuarios'
                    ],
                    [
                        'nombre_tipo_usuario' => 'Supervisor',
                        'descripcion_tipo_usuario' => 'Se encarga de ver las actividades de los usuarios , ademas puede agregar clientes y puede asignar clientes a usuarios'
                    ],
                    [
                        'nombre_tipo_usuario' => 'Publicador',
                        'descripcion_tipo_usuario' => 'Este tipo de usuario solo puede agregar conteos a las publiaciones de los clientes'
                    ]
                ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('usuarios');
        Schema::dropIfExists('tipos_usuarios');
    }
}
```

...
An a table to describe user positions
...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //para hacer insersion

class CrearTablaCargosUsuarios extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cargos_usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_cargo_usuario');
            $table->unique('id_cargo_usuario');
            $table->string('nombre_cargo', 255);
            $table->unique('nombre_cargo');
            $table->text('descripcion_cargo');
        });

        // Insert some stuff
        DB::table('cargos_usuarios')
                   ->insert(
        [ 
            [
                'nombre_cargo' => 'Gerente',
                'descripcion_cargo' => 'Es el encargado de manejar la empresa de y todas las labores ejecutivas'
            ],
            [
                'nombre_cargo' => 'Programador',
                'descripcion_cargo' => 'Se encarga de dar soporte tecnico, desarrolla sitios web y aplicaciones.'
            ],
            [
                'nombre_cargo' => 'Diseñador',
                'descripcion_cargo' => 'Realiza diversos trabajos como diseño de post, logos y otros.'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cargos_usuarios');
    }
}
...

This last tables must be migrate before "usuarios" to about issues

This is my model

...
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class usuarios extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false; //Esto es necesario para que no se produzcan errores de insersción ya que laravel los usa por predeterminado
    
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    
    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_usuario';


    public function obtener_tipo_usuario()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\tipos_usuarios', 'id_tipo_usuario', 'id_tipo_usuario');
    }


    public function obtener_cargo_usuario()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\cargos_usuarios', 'id_cargo_usuario', 'id_cargo_usuario');
    }

    public function suspender_usuario()
    {
        if ($this->estado_usuario == false) 
        {
            return 'Este usuario ya ha sido suspendido';
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->estado_usuario = false;
            $this->fecha_retiro = date("Y-m-d");
            $this->save();
            return 'usuario suspendido';    
        }
    }

    public function activar_usuario()
    {
        if ($this->estado_usuario == true) 
        {
            return 'Este usuario ya esta activo';
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->estado_usuario = true;
            $this->fecha_retiro = null;
            $this->save();
            return 'Usuario dado de alta';
        }

    }

}
```

...

this is my ususarios controller

...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\usuarios;
use DB; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; //para almacenar
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UsuariosController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Muestra el formulario para agregar usuarios
     * Este debe estar disponible solo para el administrador
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $tipos_usuarios = DB::table('tipos_usuarios')->where('nombre_tipo_usuario', '!=' ,'Administrador')->get();
        $cargos_usuarios = DB::table('cargos_usuarios')->get();
        return view('layouts/sistema/usuarios/agregar_usuario', ['tipos_usuarios' => $tipos_usuarios, 'cargos_usuarios' => $cargos_usuarios] );
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $solicitud
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $solicitud)
    {

        $solicitud->validate([
            'archivo_foto_usuario' =>['required', 'mimes:jpeg,png, webp,jpg', 'dimensions:min_width=50,min_height=50,max_width=200,min_height=200'],

            'nombre_usuario' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'apellido_usuario' =>  ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],

            'telefono_usuario' => ['required', 'regex:/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$/','unique:usuarios,telefono_usuario' ],
    

            'alias_usuario' =>  ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255','unique:usuarios,alias'],

            'contraseña_usuario' =>  ['required','min:8','regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/'],

            'correo_usuario' => ['required', 'regex:/[a-z0-9._%+-]@manilastudio.com$/', 'unique:usuarios,correo'], 

            'tipo_usuario' => 'required',
            'cargo_usuario' => 'required',
        ],  [
            'archivo_foto_usuario.required' => 'Se necesita una imagen en formato compatible',
            'archivo_foto_usuario.mimes' => 'Formato de imagen no soportado',
            'archivo_foto_usuario.dimensions' => 'La imagen debe ser de mimino 50x50 y maximo 200x200',

            'nombre_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'nombre_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',

            'apellido_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'apellido_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',

            'telefono_usuario.required' => 'Introduza un numero teléfonico valido',
            'telefono_usuario.regex' => 'El formato debe ser +50512345678',
            'telefono_usuario.unique' => 'Este número ya esta en uso',

            'alias_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'alias_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'alias_usuario.unique' => 'Esta alias ya esta en uso',

            'contraseña_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 8 letras, con números o caracteres',
            'contraseña_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 8 letras, con números o caracteres.',
            'contraseña_usuario.regex' => 'La contraseña temporal debe tener letras o números y caracteres',

            'correo_usuario.regex' => 'El correo debe usar el dominio manilastudio.com',
            'correo_usuario.required' => 'Se necesita asignar un correo electronico',
            'correo_usuario.unique' => 'Este correo ya esta en uso'
        ]);

        $nuevo_usuario = new usuarios();

        $nuevo_usuario->nombre_usuario = $solicitud->input('nombre_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->apellido_usuario = $solicitud->input('apellido_usuario');

       /**Guardar en un directorio */
        if ($solicitud->hasFile('archivo_foto_usuario')) 
        {
            $nuevo_usuario->foto_usuario  = $solicitud->archivo_foto_usuario->store('img/usuarios', 'public');
            $solicitud->file('archivo_foto_usuario')->store( 'img/usuarios/');
        }
        else
        {
            $nuevo_usuario->foto_usuario = 'img/usarios/user.png';
        }

        
        $nuevo_usuario->alias = $solicitud->input('alias_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->contraseña = $solicitud->input('contraseña_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->telefono_usuario = $solicitud->input('telefono_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->correo = $solicitud->input('correo_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->id_tipo_usuario = $solicitud->input('tipo_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->id_cargo_usuario = $solicitud->input('cargo_usuario');
        $nuevo_usuario->fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");
        $nuevo_usuario->fecha_retiro = null;
        $nuevo_usuario->respuesta_pregunta = 'hola';
        $nuevo_usuario->estado_usuario = true;
        $nuevo_usuario->save();

        return redirect('/usuarios');


    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\usuarios $id_usuario
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(usuarios $usuario)
    {
      //  $usuario = usuarios::find($usuario);
        $tipos_usuarios = DB::table('tipos_usuarios')->where('nombre_tipo_usuario', '!=' ,'Administrador')->get();
        $cargos_usuarios = DB::table('cargos_usuarios')->get();
      
       return view('layouts/sistema/usuarios/editar_usuario', ['usuario' => $usuario, 'tipos_usuarios' => $tipos_usuarios, 'cargos_usuarios' => $cargos_usuarios]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\usuarios $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $solicitud, usuarios $usuario)
    {   
       // $usuario = usuarios::findOrFail($id_usuario);
       // dd($usuario->id_usuario);
       $valido =  $solicitud->validate([
            'estado_usuario' =>['required'],
            'archivo_foto_usuario' =>['required', 'mimes:jpeg,png, webp,jpg', 'dimensions:min_width=50,min_height=50,max_width=200,min_height=200'],

            'nombre_usuario' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'apellido_usuario' =>  ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],

            'telefono_usuario' => ['required', 'regex:/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$/', Rule::unique('usuarios')->ignore($usuario) ],
 

            'alias_usuario' =>  ['required','min:3','max:255',Rule::unique('usuarios')->ignore($usuario)], 

            'contraseña_usuario' =>  ['required','min:8','regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/', Rule::unique('usuarios')->ignore($usuario)],

            'correo_usuario' => ['required', 'regex:/[a-z0-9._%+-]@manilastudio.com$/', /*'unique:usuarios,correo'*/ Rule::unique('usuarios')->ignore($usuario)], 

            'tipo_usuario' => 'required',
            'cargo_usuario' => 'required',
        ],  
        [
            'estado_usuario.required' => "Debe fijarse un estado para este usuario",

           'archivo_foto_usuario.required' => 'Se necesita una imagen en formato compatible',
            'archivo_foto_usuario.mimes' => 'Formato de imagen no soportado',
            'archivo_foto_usuario.dimensions' => 'La imagen debe ser de mimino 50x50 y maximo 200x200',

            'nombre_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'nombre_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',

            'apellido_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'apellido_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',

            'telefono_usuario.required' => 'Introduza un numero teléfonico valido',
            'telefono_usuario.regex' => 'El formato debe ser +50512345678',
            'telefono_usuario.unique' => 'Este número ya esta en uso',

            'alias_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'alias_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 4 caracteres.',
            'alias_usuario.unique' => 'Esta alias ya esta en uso',

            'contraseña_usuario.required' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 8 letras, con números o caracteres',
            'contraseña_usuario.min' => 'Campo requerido, introduzca al menos 8 letras, con números o caracteres.',
            'contraseña_usuario.regex' => 'La contraseña temporal debe tener letras o números y caracteres',

            'correo_usuario.regex' => 'El correo debe usar el dominio manilastudio.com',
            'correo_usuario.required' => 'Se necesita asignar un correo electronico',
            'correo_usuario.unique' => 'Este correo ya esta en uso'
        ]);

        $usuario->nombre_usuario = $solicitud->input('nombre_usuario');
        $usuario->apellido_usuario = $solicitud->input('apellido_usuario');

       /**Guardar en un directorio */
        if ($solicitud->hasFile('archivo_foto_usuario')) 
        {
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($usuario->foto_usuario);
            $usuario->foto_usuario  = $solicitud->archivo_foto_usuario->store('img/usuarios', 'public');
            $solicitud->file('archivo_foto_usuario')->store( 'img/usuarios/');
        }
        else
        {
            $usuario->foto_usuario = 'img/usarios/user.png';
        }

       // dd($solicitud->hasFile('archivo_foto_usuario'));
        
        $usuario->alias = $solicitud->input('alias_usuario');
        $usuario->contraseña = $solicitud->input('contraseña_usuario');
        $usuario->telefono_usuario = $solicitud->input('telefono_usuario');
        $usuario->correo = $solicitud->input('correo_usuario');
        $usuario->id_tipo_usuario = $solicitud->input('tipo_usuario');
        $usuario->id_cargo_usuario = $solicitud->input('cargo_usuario');
        $usuario->fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");

        if ($solicitud->estado_usuario == 0) 
        {
            $usuario->fecha_retiro = date("Y-m-d");
        }
        
        $usuario->respuesta_pregunta = 'hola';
        $usuario->estado_usuario = $solicitud->estado_usuario;

        $usuario->save();


    
        return redirect('/usuarios');
    }
}
...

and this is my view 

...
@section('titulo', 'Modificar datos de Usuario')
<x-master>
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="text-left">
        <h1 class="font-weight-bolder"> 
            Modificar Datos de Usuario
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
    <form id="formulario-agregar-usuario" class="form" method="POST" action="/usuarios/{{ $usuario->id_usuario }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="border rounded p-2 bg-white">
                        <div class="border rounded">
                        <img class="border rounded-circle w-100 img-fluid mr-3" src="/storage/{{$usuario->foto_usuario}}" alt="" title="Nombre Usuario"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input class="btn" type="file" name="archivo_foto_usuario">
                    @error('archivo_foto_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('archivo_foto_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <input type="radio" name="estado_usuario" id="activo" value="1" @if ($usuario->estado_usuario == 1 ) checked="checked" @endif>
                        <label for="activo" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase text-success" >Activo</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="estado_usuario" id="suspender" value="0" @if ($usuario->estado_usuario == 0 ) checked="checked"@endif>
                        <label for="suspender" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase text-danger">Suspender</label>
                        @error('nombre_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('estado_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ml-lg-4 ml-sm-0">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtNombre_usuario" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Nombre Usuario</label>
                            <input  id="txtNombre_usuario" class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre_usuario" value="{{ $usuario->nombre_usuario }}">
                            @error('nombre_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('nombre_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtApellido_correo" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Apellido Usuario</label>
                            <input  id="txtApellido_usuario" class="form-control" type="text" name="apellido_usuario" value="{{ $usuario->apellido_usuario }}">
                            @error('apellido_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('apellido_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtTelefono_Usuario" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Telefono Usuario</label>
                            <input  id="txtTelefono_Usuario" type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefono_usuario" placeholder="ejemplo +505812345678" value="{{ $usuario->telefono_usuario }}">
                            @error('telefono_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('telefono_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                          </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtemail" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Correo</label>
                            <input  id="txtemail" class="form-control" type="email"  name="correo_usuario" value="{{ $usuario->correo_usuario }}">
                            @error('correo_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('correo_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="sltTipo_Usuario" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Tipo de Usuario</label>
                            <select id="sltTipo_Usuario" class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario" >
                                @foreach ($tipos_usuarios as $tipo)
                                <option value="{{$tipo->id_tipo_usuario}}" @if ($tipo->id_tipo_usuario == $usuario->id_tipo_usuario) selected="selected" @endif>{{$tipo->nombre_tipo_usuario }}</option>    
                               @endforeach
                            </select>
                          </div>                         
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="sltCargo_Usuario" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Cargo de Usuario</label>
                            <select id="sltCargo_Usuario" class="form-control" name="cargo_usuario">
                                @foreach ($cargos_usuarios as $cargo)
                                <option value="{{$cargo->id_cargo_usuario}}"  @if ($cargo->id_cargo_usuario == $usuario->id_cargo_usuario) selected="selected" @endif>{{$cargo->nombre_cargo}}</option> 
                                @endforeach 
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtAlias_usuario" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Alias Usuario</label>
                            <input  id="txtAlias_usuario" class="form-control" type="text" name="alias_usuario" value="@if (old('alias_usuario') !== null ) {{old('alias_usuario')}}@else {{$usuario->alias}}@endif">
                            @error('alias_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('alias_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="txtcontraseña" class="font-weight-bolder text-uppercase">Contraseña Temporal</label>
                        <input  id="txtcontraseña" class="form-control" type="password" name="contraseña_usuario" value="{{ $usuario->contraseña}}">
                            @error('contraseña_usuario') <div class="validacion" >{{ $errors->first('contraseña_usuario')}}</div> @enderror
                            <div class="validacion" ></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modificar Usuario</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>

          </form>
    </div>
</div>
</x-master>
```

...

And this is the error that I get

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'alias_usuario' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `usuarios` where `alias_usuario` = rytertertcc and `id_usuario` <> 4)

I checked the official laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique
so I procceded to implement this Rule::unique('usuarios')->ignore($usuario)] so if I update a user alias that is unique piece of data but no the email or telephone that are also uniques pieces of data I should have not this problem,

The other question related to this [Laravel: Validation unique on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587833/laravel-validation-unique-on-update) has not been useful for this matter.

I really appreciate the help if possible, thank you very much.

Comment: Just added a key which you want to ask. I just feel hard to understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input name doesn't match the column name, you'll have to pass the column name when you create the rule. Per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique), if your database uses a different column than what you're passing, then you need to pass along the column name as well:

```
Rule::unique('usuarios', 'alias')->ignore($usuario)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this was what solve the issue now I can update with no issue, just a quick question, do you think I should keep the names of the fields in forms, the same as those in the model? just to keep consistency.

Comment: I find it helps if the field names are the same in most cases. It's easier to track things down, as well as map fields between the database and post fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as well:

I'm not clear with your database structure but I can give you the example like below:

**`users`** is a table name.

**name** is column that you want to validate.

```
'name' => 'unique:users,name,' . request('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

In update function you can use

```
'telefono_usuario' => 'unique:usuarios,telefono_usuario,' . $usuario->id_usuario,
```

**telefono_usuario** as your field name

**unique:usuarios** is your model

**$usuario->id_usuario** is id which you are going to update

Comment: This resulted in a error where the internal query engine could not find the field SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `usuarios` where `telefono_usuario` = +00112345678 and `id` <> 5)

Comment: Looks like you didn't defined primary key in Model.
Please try 

**protected $primaryKey = 'id_usuario';**

if your table primary key is "id_usuario"