# Laravel validation throws error on updating same unique value

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form which has an input `name`. I want to update a database table through that form. The only condition is, the `name` must be unique. So this is what I did for validation in the backend:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:myTableName'
]);
```

It's working as expected. It throws this error `"The name has already been taken."` when I try to enter a name which already exists in the database. But the problem I have with this is, when I'm updating the same entry from database without any change (I.E. I go to edit form, do nothing, update the form), it shows me the same error. In this case, I don't want the error as I'm updating the same value. How can I achieve this with laravel validation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Validation unique on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587833/laravel-validation-unique-on-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use following code

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('myTableName')->ignore($yourVariable->id)],
]);
```

Add header section below code

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

[More Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942367/how-validate-unique-email-out-of-the-user-that-is-updating-it-in-laravel/53948993#53948993)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the table id, to ignore that field from validation

```
'name' => 'required|unique:myTableName,name,' . $table->id,
```

With custom Rule :

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'name' => ['required', Rule::unique('myTableName', 'name')->ignore($table->id)],
```